# Need to ZIP an entire directory using Node.js

Tags: node.js, zip

I need to zip an entire directory using Node.js. I'm currently using node-zip and each time the process runs it generates an invalid ZIP file (as you can see from [this Github issue](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/41)).

Is there another, better, Node.js option that will allow me to ZIP up a directory?

EDIT: I ended up using [archiver](https://npmjs.org/package/archiver)

```
writeZip = function(dir,name) {
var zip = new JSZip(),
    code = zip.folder(dir),
    output = zip.generate(),
    filename = ['jsd-',name,'.zip'].join('');

fs.writeFileSync(baseDir + filename, output);
console.log('creating ' + filename);
};
```

sample value for parameters:

```
dir = /tmp/jsd-<randomstring>/
name = <randomstring>
```

**UPDATE:** For those asking about the implementation I used, [here's a link to my downloader](https://github.com/commadelimited/JSDownloader/blob/master/routes/download.js):

Comment: Someone on Twitter suggested the child_process API, and simply call the system ZIP: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: I've tried the child_process approach. It's got two caveats. 

**1)** unix `zip` command includes all parent folder hierarchy of the current working directory in the zipped file. This might be ok for you, it wasn't for me. Also changing the current working directory in child_process somehow doesn't effect the results. 

**2)** To overcome this problem, you have to use `pushd` to jump into the folder you will zip and `zip -r` , but since `pushd`  is built into bash and not /bin/sh you need to use /bin/bash also. In my specific case this wasn't possible. Just a heads up.

Comment: @johnozbay node's `child_process.exec` api lets you specify the cwd from where you want to run the command. Changing the CWD does fix the issue of the parent folder hierarchy. It also fixes the issue of not needing `pushd`. I fully recommend child_process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49970368/2757916 native nodejs solution using child_process api. 2 lines of code. No third party libs.

Comment: @GovindRai Many thanks!

Answer (score 195, accepted):

I ended up using [archiver](https://npmjs.org/package/archiver) lib. Works great.

**[Example](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/tree/master/examples)**

```
var file_system = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');

var output = file_system.createWriteStream('target.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip');

output.on('close', function () {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

archive.on('error', function(err){
    throw err;
});

archive.pipe(output);

// append files from a sub-directory, putting its contents at the root of archive
archive.directory(source_dir, false);

// append files from a sub-directory and naming it `new-subdir` within the archive
archive.directory('subdir/', 'new-subdir');

archive.finalize();
```

Comment: There don't seem to be any examples of how to do this, do you mind sharing what you did?

Comment: archiver, unfortunately, doesn't support Unicode characters in filenames as of now. Reported to https://github.com/ctalkington/node-archiver/issues/90.

Comment: How do I include all files and directories, recursively (also the hidden files/directories)?

Comment: Archiver makes this even simpler now. Rather than using the bulk() method, you can now use directory(): https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver#directory-dirpath-destpath-data

Comment: The .directory() method does work, but when the archive is unzipped the file tree to the directory exists.  Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Shall I call `output.close()` somewhere?

Comment: `.bulk` is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for this, I had troubles both with adm-zip and node-zip (corrupted binary files), this seem to work fast and clean (my application builds XXX MB zips composed by a lot of small videos)

Comment: Bulk has been deprecated. https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/compare/1.3.0...2.0.0

Comment: How to add source directory to bulk zip?

Comment: I still have an issue, where when I open the zip I created, all the files are there, except the image files, and if the images are there, most of the pixels are the same solid color

Answer (score 129):

I'm not going to show something new, just wanted to summarise the solutions above for those who like Promises as much as I do .

```
const archiver = require('archiver');

/**
 * @param {String} sourceDir: /some/folder/to/compress
 * @param {String} outPath: /path/to/created.zip
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function zipDirectory(sourceDir, outPath) {
  const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 }});
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outPath);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    archive
      .directory(sourceDir, false)
      .on('error', err => reject(err))
      .pipe(stream)
    ;

    stream.on('close', () => resolve());
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

Hope it will help someone

Comment: what exactly is "out" here? i assume source is the path of directory

Comment: @Tarun full zip's path like: /User/mypc/mydir/test.zip

Comment: @ekaj_03 please make sure that you have enough rights for specified directory

Comment: I found the easiest way to add files and zip in Nodejs at this link : https://jsonworld.wordpress.com/2019/09/07/how-to-zip-and-download-files-in-nodejs-express/

Comment: Can someone please share code that can unzip the above zip? I have tried many things and always end up with "there are no headers at the end of the file / headers are incorrect" error. Thanks.

Comment: @AmeyParundekar could you please share your code so we can investigate the issue?

Comment: Make sure to catch write error from stream too `stream.on('error', ex => reject(ex));`

Comment: Thanks!!! This helped me!!! Saved time!!! Here's an adaptation using `import` `from`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70958944

Comment: If you are using Typescript, you might need an additional dependencies: `@types/archiver`

Comment: I needed to archive files in a node prebuild script, but kept ending up with archives that were 0 bytes long. Wrapping everything in a Promise worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

### Use Node's native `child_process` api to accomplish this.

No need for third party libs. Two lines of code.

```
const child_process = require("child_process");
child_process.execSync(`zip -r <DESIRED_NAME_OF_ZIP_FILE_HERE> *`, {
  cwd: <PATH_TO_FOLDER_YOU_WANT_ZIPPED_HERE>
});
```

The example above showcases the synchronous API. You can also use `child_process.exec(path, options, callback)` if you want async behavior. There are a lot more [options](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) you can specify other than `cwd` to further fine-tune your request.

---

**If you don't have the ZIP utility:**

This question is *specifically* asks about the `zip` utility for archiving/compression purposes. Therefore, this example assumes you have the `zip` utility installed on your system. For completeness sakes, some operating systems may not have utility installed by default. In that case you have at least three options:

1. Work with the archiving/compression utility that is native to your platform

   Replace the shell command in the above Node.js code with code from your system. For example, linux distros usually come with `tar`/`gzip` utilities:

   `tar -cfz <DESIRED_NAME_OF_ZIP_FILE_HERE> <PATH_TO_FOLDER_YOU_WANT_ZIPPED_HERE>`.

   This is a nice option as you don't need to install anything new onto your operating system or manage another dependency (kind of the whole point for this answer).
2. Obtain the `zip` binary for your OS/distribution.

   For example on Ubuntu: `apt install zip`.

   The ZIP utility is tried and tested for decades, it's fairly ubiquitous and it's a safe choice. Do a quick google search or go to the creator, Info-ZIP's, website for downloadable binaries.
3. Use a third party library/module (of which there are plenty on NPM).

   I don't prefer this option. However, if you don't really care to understand the native methods and introducing a new dependency is a non-issue, this is also a valid option.

Comment: Unfortunately only works on systems that have `zip`.

Comment: Went for this solution just for the sake of avoiding dozens of external libraries on my project

Comment: it makes sense, but if i'm not incorrect this is screwing over windows users again. Please think of the windows users!

Comment: @MathijsSegers haha! that's why i included a link to the binary so windows users can get it too! :)

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work for a directory within a project rather than a computer directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "within a project"?

Comment: @GovindRai What I meant was how to access a directory within my app and use `fs.readdir` on let's say  `'project_root/server/modules/auth'` but I was actually able to make it work using `path.resolve(__dirname) + '/rest_of_path'`.

Comment: Assuming that a given library is installed in the underlying platform defeats the purpose of the package.json dependency manifest. Even more importantly, if Zip is only available on MacOS and you deploy to a linux environment you are doomed :D

Comment: Just a reminder for folks who find this solution inadequate because it relies of the  zip binary: this question is specifically asking how to `zip` files. It's not asking for a cross platform archiving solution. The last paragraph is dedicated for this purpose of obtaining the zip utility across platforms.

Comment: All the Node zip libs I checked out were like toys compared to the real thing.  +1 for the reminder, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to stream the input and stream the resulting zip archive out for an API route?

I am using streaming with a Node library to stream results but curious if it is possible using exec and not using the tool.

Comment: Getting error with zip command, although when i use zip command with terminal it works fine!!
/bin/sh: 1: zip: not found

Answer (score 20):

This is another library which zips the folder in one line : 
[zip-local](https://github.com/Mostafa-Samir/zip-local)

```
var zipper = require('zip-local');

zipper.sync.zip("./hello/world/").compress().save("pack.zip");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, unlike dozen of others available on internet or mentioned above, which always generated 'zero bytes' file for me

Answer (score 13):

`Archive.bulk` is now deprecated, the new method to be used for this is [glob](https://archiverjs.com/docs/Archiver.html#glob):

```
var fileName =   'zipOutput.zip'
var fileOutput = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);

fileOutput.on('close', function () {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

archive.pipe(fileOutput);
archive.glob("../dist/**/*"); //some glob pattern here
archive.glob("../dist/.htaccess"); //another glob pattern
// add as many as you like
archive.on('error', function(err){
    throw err;
});
archive.finalize();
```

Comment: Was wondering about this, they said bulk was deprecated but didn't suggest which function to use instead.

Comment: How do you specify the "source" directory?

Comment: Try once the below approach: https://jsonworld.wordpress.com/2019/09/07/how-to-zip-and-download-files-in-nodejs-express/

Comment: 2020: archive.directory() is much simpler!

Answer (score 9):

To include all files and directories:

```
archive.bulk([
  {
    expand: true,
    cwd: "temp/freewheel-bvi-120",
    src: ["**/*"],
    dot: true
  }
]);
```

It uses node-glob(https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) underneath, so any matching expression compatible with that will work.

Comment: .bulk is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

To pipe the result to the response object (scenarios where there is a need to download the zip rather than store locally)

```
 archive.pipe(res);
```

Sam's hints for accessing the content of the directory worked for me.

```
src: ["**/*"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `archiver` is not compatible with the new version of webpack for a long time, I recommend using [zip-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-lib).

```
var zl = require("zip-lib");

zl.archiveFolder("path/to/folder", "path/to/target.zip").then(function () {
    console.log("done");
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: You have an example to integrate `zip-lib` into my webpack project? 

Answer (score 4):

As today, I'm using AdmZip and works great:

```
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
export async function archiveFile() {
  try {
    const zip = new AdmZip();
    const outputDir = "/output_file_dir.zip";
    zip.addLocalFolder("./yourFolder")
    zip.writeZip(outputDir);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Something went wrong ${e}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adm-zip has problems just compressing an existing archive https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/issues/64 as well as corruption with compressing binary files.

I've also ran into compression corruption issues with node-zip https://github.com/daraosn/node-zip/issues/4

node-archiver is the only one that seems to work well to compress but it doesn't have any uncompress functionality.

Comment: About which node-archiver are you talking about? : github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver ; github.com/richardbolt/node-archiver

Comment: @firian He did not say Archiver, he said Adm-zip.

Comment: @FrancisPelland Umm, in the last sentence he wrote "_node-archiver is the only one that seems to work_" - that's what I'm refering to.

Comment: i think he meatn https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver

Answer (score 3):

I have found this small library that encapsulates what you need.

```
npm install zip-a-folder

const zipAFolder = require('zip-a-folder');
await zipAFolder.zip('/path/to/the/folder', '/path/to/archive.zip');
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-a-folder

Comment: Is it possible to add parameters to make zip folder ? like compressed level and size if so how to do that?

Comment: Downvoting because `zip-a-folder` is not a vaild identifier.

Answer (score 1):

`import` `...` `from` answer based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51518100

To **zip single directory**

```
import archiver from 'archiver';
import fs from 'fs';

export default zipDirectory;

/**
 * From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51518100
 * @param {String} sourceDir: /some/folder/to/compress
 * @param {String} outPath: /path/to/created.zip
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function zipDirectory(sourceDir, outPath) {
  const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 }});
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outPath);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    archive
      .directory(sourceDir, false)
      .on('error', err => reject(err))
      .pipe(stream)
    ;

    stream.on('close', () => resolve());
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

To **zip multiple directories**:

```
import archiver from 'archiver';
import fs from 'fs';

export default zipDirectories;

/**
 * Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51518100
 * @param {String} sourceDir: /some/folder/to/compress
 * @param {String} outPath: /path/to/created.zip
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function zipDirectories(sourceDirs, outPath) {
  const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 }});
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outPath);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var result = archive;
    sourceDirs.forEach(sourceDir => {
      result = result.directory(sourceDir, false);
    });
    result
      .on('error', err => reject(err))
      .pipe(stream)
    ;

    stream.on('close', () => resolve());
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in a simple way:

Install `zip-dir` :

```
npm install zip-dir
```

and use it

```
var zipdir = require('zip-dir');

let foldername =  src_path.split('/').pop() 
    zipdir(<<src_path>>, { saveTo: 'demo.zip' }, function (err, buffer) {

    });
```

Comment: is it possible to add parameters to make zip folder ? like compressed level and size if so how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping archiver to emulate JSZip, as refactoring through my project woult take too much effort. I understand Archiver might not be the best choice, but here you go.

```
// USAGE:
const zip=JSZipStream.to(myFileLocation)
    .onDone(()=>{})
    .onError(()=>{});

zip.file('something.txt','My content');
zip.folder('myfolder').file('something-inFolder.txt','My content');
zip.finalize();

// NodeJS file content:
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var archiver = require('archiver');

  function zipper(archive, settings) {
    return {
        output: null,
        streamToFile(dir) {
            const output = fs.createWriteStream(dir);
            this.output = output;
            archive.pipe(output);

            return this;
        },
        file(location, content) {
            if (settings.location) {
                location = path.join(settings.location, location);
            }
            archive.append(content, { name: location });
            return this;
        },
        folder(location) {
            if (settings.location) {
                location = path.join(settings.location, location);
            }
            return zipper(archive, { location: location });
        },
        finalize() {
            archive.finalize();
            return this;
        },
        onDone(method) {
            this.output.on('close', method);
            return this;
        },
        onError(method) {
            this.output.on('error', method);
            return this;
        }
    };
}

exports.JSzipStream = {
    to(destination) {
        console.log('stream to',destination)
        const archive = archiver('zip', {
            zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
        });
        return zipper(archive, {}).streamToFile(destination);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");

const { createGzip } = require("node:zlib");
const { pipeline } = require("node:stream");
const { createReadStream, createWriteStream } = require("node:fs");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const gzip = createGzip();
  const source = createReadStream("hotellists.json");
  const destination = createWriteStream("hotellists.json.gz");

  pipeline(source, gzip, destination, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("An error occurred:", err);
      process.exitCode = 1;
    }
    
  });
});
app.listen(2020, () => console.log("server in on"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.