# How to zip a directory with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, compression, directory

I have a folder I need to zip on my node server to send over on a buffer stream.  What would be the best way to compress the directory?

I've tried using npm [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip), but I can only find a function for compressing individual files, not an entire directory... is this even possible with adm-zip?  If not is anybody aware of another package that could do this?

Sorry if this is an incredibly obvious question, I'm new to node.js

Comment: You can refer to [need to zip an entire directory using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641243/need-to-zip-an-entire-directory-using-node-js).

Comment: Ah thank you, I will close this question