# Node.js ArchiverJS library not writing to output filestream in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, archiverjs

I'm trying to zip the contents of a directory using [node-archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641243/need-to-zip-an-entire-directory-using-node-js). The function is running in AWS Lambda in the Node.js runtime environment.

My function is as follows:

```
function zipDirectory(source, outputTarget) {
    var archive = archiver("zip");
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputTarget, { flags: 'w' });

    stream.on("close", () => {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        archive.pipe(stream);
        archive.on("error", err => reject(err))
        archive.directory(source, false);
        archive.finalize();
        stream.close();
        resolve();
    });
}
```

The result is that the zip is created but the file size is zero:

```
INFO    0 total bytes
INFO    archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.
```

I'm also unable to extract the archive with the following error.

```
INFO    Error: end of central directory record signature not found
```

**Notes:**

1. The source directory definitely exists, is populated, and the path is correct.
2. Everything is being written to the `/tmp/` directory to which AWS Lambda allows us read and write access.
3. I tried uploading the `zip` binary with the Lambda deployment package and running it as a child process, but apparently, that is not supported because it's a 32-bit package. If you have alternatives that I could use to zip directories outside of node that would work in Lambda's runtime, please do tell.

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured my mistake out.

1. `archive.finalize()` returns a promise and the function was returning before the archiving was complete.
2. Calling `stream.close()` is unnecessary as `archive.finalize()` does that for you, so the stream was being closed regardless of whether the archiving was complete or not.

The correct code looks like this:

```
function zipDirectory(source, outputTarget) {
    var archive = archiver("zip");
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputTarget, { flags: 'w' });

    stream.on("close", () => {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    });

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        archive.pipe(stream);
        archive.on("error", err => reject(err))
        archive.directory(source, false);
        await archive.finalize();
        resolve();
    });
}
```