# How to zip and unzip a directory using zlib without additional `npm` packages NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, zip, zlib

As the title implies I am interested in zipping a directory and then unzipping it using Zlib without any external dependencies is that possible and how?

Notes: I'm not interested in using native methods or npm dependencies.

Comment: You can use the child_process api to do this natively https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641243/need-to-zip-an-entire-directory-using-node-js/49970368#49970368

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I can use require("child_process").exec("Command", (error, stdout, stderr) => {//Logic} but that doesn't answer the question.